# How to reduce Hardware reserved memory on ASUS motherboards?

Tags: windows-7, memory, motherboard, bios, 32-bit

I have read lots of topics but i still couldn't lower the hardware reserved memory which is over 1GB

There is only 2.21 GB RAM that is being usable by the OS.
I had another computer where the usable RAM was 3.5GB. Though, that was Gigabyte motherboard which has no built-in graphic.

The OS is Windows 7 Ultimate 32Bit

Most of the hardware reserved memory i saw is being reserved for the PCI Express with most of its addresses are being reserved for the AMD Radeon.

[image]

You can see that there is the reserved addresses from `90000000` to `DFFFFFFF` on PCI bus.

I have updated the BIOS but that didn't help.
I also tried the Msconfig boot settings to uncheck the maximum memory but it did nothing.

Motherboard is ASUS TUF Z270 MARK 2

Are there any BIOS settings that i can disable to save more RAM?

Comment: You don’t have a built-in GPU.  How do I know this, because you have a Intel Processor, and a AMD GPU.  Solution to your problem is to use a 64-bit installation of Windows.

Comment: What i meant by i have is that there is a "port" in the motherboard for it. DVI port but i am not using it.

Comment: Ok;  You still have a dedicated GPU.  Memory being reserved for hardware is absolutely normal.  It’s only using 512 MB by the way.

Comment: Oh, i thought the dedicated GPU has it's own memory. My bad. So the only solution is to use 64bit OS :(

Comment: You actually want maximum memory to be checked.  Your GPU has VRAM, but, it still needs system memory.

Comment: Ok that seems reasonable. I have checked the Maximum memory but it doesn't help. I think i will just stick with your solution of installing a 64bit OS. Thanks for your help.